# mysql get order number

Tags: mysql, list, ranking

I have the following structure

---

Country    -       UserId    -     Points

840          23          24
840                         32                     31
840                         22                     38
840                         15                     35
840                         10                     20
250                         15                     33
724                         17                     12

etc

I want to get the position of user in the ranking of each country accordin points
I'm using

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 Num, Country, UserId, points 
from users , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r  
where country=840 order by points DESC ;
```

I want to get the position of a single user inside his country

In this example, in country 840, if I select user id=23, I'll get position 4

Country    -       UserId    -     Points- Order
840         22         38        1
840         15         35        2
840         32         31        3
840         23         24        4
840        10          20           5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing:

```
select * from (
  select @rownum: = @rownum + 1 Num,
        Country,
        UserId,
        points
  from users, (select @rownum: = 0) r
  where country = 840
  order by points desc
) a
where userId = 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your query you'll receive row number in your results so it's not what you want to. Best way is to generate positions and save them to separated column. This way you'll be able to select it easy and there will be no need to recalculate it each time (which is very important).

To do it you can modify your query to update rows instead of selecting it.